# Extract a file from a huge tarball remotely

Tags: tar

Is it possible to extract one file from a huge remote tarball (.tar.gz) quickly by reading the necessary parts only?

I tried streaming the tarball using ssh but it downloads the entire file first.

Comment: A tar by definition is a compressed file ..  Not a directory .. So the only way to get something out of a `tar` file is to download and extract all files ..  Then peel out the file you want .. Discard the rest.   No two ways about it.

Comment: I see what you are saying...